# Unmute audio input (microphone) in OSX programatically

Tags: objective-c, macos, audio, input, applescript

**OSX 10.10.3**, also reproducible on 10.8

The current state of audio input in System Preferences is:

- Input volume is set to 0
- When I speak into microphone I see **no** animation of the sound bar

Is it possible to recover audio input from that state in AppleScript?

## Edition 1

Basically, this script doesn't work, the microphone stays muted, despite of the fact that the volume caret is set to maximum.

```
set volume input volume 100
```

## Edition 2

The following AppleScript works:

```
tell application "System Events"
set volume input volume 100
end tell
tell application "System Preferences"
set current pane to pane id "com.apple.preference.sound"
end tell
tell application "System Events"
tell process "System Preferences"
set visible to false
click radio button "input" of tab group 1 of window "Sound"
perform action "AXIncrement" of slider 1 of group 2 of tab group 1 of window "Sound"
end tell
end tell
tell application "System Preferences"
quit
end tell
```

But unfortunately it cannot be executed without a permission from user to Accessibility (that requires relatively difficult actions from user).

## Edition 3

I can consider a solution in any language: AppleScript, Objective-C, Java, C++.

Comment: why doesn't it work? can you explain more?

Comment: try it. Go to System Preferences, mute mic manually, run the script, speak to microphone, it will grab no voice. To fix this, touch the caret in System Preferences.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this command to unmute:

```
set volume input volume 100
```

To run it from the command line do this:

```
osascript -e "set volume input volume 100"
```

I just tested it, it seems to work for me.

Comment: Same thing, doesn't matter for how I run it. Could you please follow the steps I described and then test in any online "test microphone" website?

Comment: If it truly doesn't work, you should report it on the apple.discussions forums.

Comment: I would, could you please confirm that you have the same behavior?

Comment: It works for me.  I muted in Sys Pref, ran my osascript, went to https://www.onlinemictest.com/microphone-test-in-adobe-flash and I see activity.

Comment: Perhaps, you should state your OS version if it doesn't work?

Comment: I Added additional info in the question. I use 10.10.3.

Comment: Can anyone confirm on 10.10?