# How can I monitor Line In input with Realtek audio? (New Windows driver removed option to unmute it)

Tags: windows, audio, monitoring, latency, realtek

I connect a MacBook through a 3.5mm jack cable to another computer's line in input jack in the motherboard which has Realtek Audio (Windows). This enables me to use a pair of speakers connected to this last PC and hear both mac and pc through the same speakers simultaneously.
I used to be able to go the Speaker Properties panel and **unmute** the Rear Input. This way it uses direct monitoring so you don't experience any latency on the macbook's playback.

[image: Windows Speaker Properties]

Some time ago a driver update seems to have removed the Level fader of the inputs together with its mute toggle :O
Now, to achieve the same, I'm only left with this option which introduces latency in the audio playback:
Enabling **Listen to this device** in the Rear input Recording properties.

[image: Listen to this device]

So is there another way to regain this functionality?
Is there something like what's suggested in this other question?
[Unmute audio input (microphone) in OSX programatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33679462/unmute-audio-input-microphone-in-osx-programatically)
Basically some command to unmute the direct monitoring of the Line In audio input on Windows, or maybe an app that controls the drivers?
Realtek audio console doesn't provide this option :(

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same problem, but it's not because of the driver. The culprit is the new realtek audio control which has removed the lever for audio monitoring level. You have to use an old version of realtek control panel to make it work.
For example try downloading audio drivers for this motherboard
https://www.asrock.com/mb/intel/Z97M%20Pro4/index.la.asp#Download
Unzip it and look for the file RAVCpl64.exe under the Vista64 folder.

Run this and you'll get the good old control panel back! Works like a charm.
I suggest you put a shorcut on your desktop for ease of access.

I just did this and uninstalled the new control panel which sucks.

I wonder why Realtek chose to remove functionality from their software, really bad idea!